# How to make a local notification alert with sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8.1

I want to set sound in local notification when my app in foregroundmode. i m try lot of thing . please help me.

```
      UInt32 flag = 0;
   SystemSoundID soundID;
        int err = AudioServicesSetProperty(kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound,
                                       sizeof(UInt32),
                                       &UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName,
                                       sizeof(UInt32),
                                       &flag);

        NSLog(@"%d",(unsigned int)err);

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to launch a local notification with a sound you can use the `soundName` property:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30];
localNotif.alertBody = @"Hey!";
localNotif.alerttitle = @"Notification!";

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

With `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName` the notification will use the default sound, use a filename instead for a custom sound.

More on this property in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILocalNotification/soundName).